# Mbed Cortex-m hardfault when sending data via TCP

Tags: mbed, tcp-ip

I have a TCPSocket* object which holds a connection to a client. This object is passed to another object to send data back to the client:

```
    uint32_t count = 10;

    char message[4]; 



    message[0] = count & 0xff;

    message[1] = (count >> 8) & 0xff;

    message[2] = (count >> 16) & 0xff;

    message[3] = (count >> 24) & 0xff;



    client->send(&message, strlen(message));
```

When this part of the program is called, the following appears on the serial line, and no data is received by the client:

```
    ++ MbedOS Fault Handler ++



                                                                                                          FaultType: HardFault



                                                                                                                              Context:

   R0   : 00000000

                  R1   : 10008000

                                 R2   : 00000004

                                                R3   : 2007C000

                                                               R4   : 10000914

                                                                              R5   : 00000000

                                                                                             R6   : 00000000

                                                                                                            R7   : 10004330

                                                                                                                           R8   : 10004320

       R9   : FFFFF435

                      R10  : 00000000

                                     R11  : 00000000

                                                    R12  : 00012AC1

                                                                   SP   : 10002AF0

                                                                                  LR   : 0000D1A1

                                                                                                 PC   : 00005938

                                                                                                                xPSR : 21000000

                                                                                                                               PSP  : 10002AD0

           MSP  : 10007FD8

                          CPUID: 412FC230

                                         HFSR : 40000000

                                                        MMFSR: 00000000

                                                                       BFSR : 00000082

                                                                                     UFSR : 00000000

                                                                                                     DFSR : 0000000A

                                                                                                                    AFSR : 00000000

                                                                                                                                   BFAR : 10008010

               Mode : Thread

                            Priv : Privileged

                                             Stack: PSP



                                                       -- MbedOS Fault Handler --







                                                                                 ++ MbedOS Error Info ++

                                                                                                        Error Status: 0x80FF013D Code: 317 Module: 255

                   Error Message: Fault exception

                                                 Location: 0xD337

                                                                 Error Value: 0x5938

                                                                                    Current Thread: main  Id: 0x10002B48 Entry: 0xD7D7 StackSize: 0x1000 StackMem: 0x10001B48 SP: 0x10007F88

                                                          For more info, visit: https://armmbed.github.io/mbedos-error/?error=0x80FF013D

     -- MbedOS Error Info --
```

Everything is in one thread so I cant see what could be causing this.

These are the relevant parts of the program:

main:

```
// Network interface
EthernetInterface net;

TCPSocket listener; //listens for incoming connection requests
TCPSocket* client;


CommandProcessor commandProcessor(client);

int main(){

int remaining;
    int rcount;
    char *p;
    char *buffer = new char[16];
    nsapi_size_or_error_t result;

    int n = net.set_network("192.168.1.103","255.255.255.0","192.168.1.2");
    pc.printf("\n Success? %d\n", n);
    net.connect();

    listener.open(&net);
    listener.bind(3045);

    listener.listen(1);

    client = listener.accept(NULL);
    client->set_timeout(1000);

    led1 = 1;
    while(1) {


        int remaining = 16;
        int rcount = 0;
        p = buffer;

        while (remaining > 0 && 0 < (result = client->recv(p, remaining))) {
            p += result;
            rcount += result;
            remaining -= result;
        }

        if (remaining == 0) //full message received
        {

            commandProcessor.process(buffer);

            }


       }
}
```

CommandProcessor:

```
CommandProcessor::CommandProcessor(TCPSocket* client)
{
    this->client = client;

}


void CommandProcessor::process(char* message)
{

    switch(message[0]) { //Command is first byte of message

    case 0x3: { 

     uint32_t count = 10 ;


    char* message = new char[4];

    message[0] = count & 0xff;
    message[1] = (count >> 8) & 0xff;
    message[2] = (count >> 16) & 0xff;
    message[3] = (count >> 24) & 0xff;

    client->send(message, sizeof(message));
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 4):

[Referring to initial question where `message` was defined as `char message[4];`]

1. message[] is being put on the stack. By the time the TCP stack comes to send the data is the stack still valid?
2. strlen is not the way to determine the length of something that is not a string! Use sizeof(message) instead.
3. Check the lifetime of the TCPSocket object as well.

Comment: Of course, send doesn't necessarily send the data by the time the send function has returned, does it? I'll make some changes and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: The TCPSocket object persists for the duration of the program. It is declared in the main file.

Comment: Can you post the whole program, cut down to the bare bones that show the problem?

Comment: The program is quite large so I'll edit out all the irrelevant stuff and post here

Comment: I've added the program to the question. Cheers! :)

Comment: sizeof() is also not what you want, use the explicit size of the message you just explicitly built, not the size of the pointer to it.  And are you sure what you are allocating there is not a memory leak?  Overall your program seems to be full of oversights and mistakes, debugging issues with a network stack on an MCU will be hard enough, your code needs to be of much higher quality to stand a chance.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, could you please elaborate on what you mean by oversights and mistakes, besides using sizeof()? The code in main was copied from the mbed example page.

As for what I'm allocating, there will be a memory leak as there is no delete. I used DMA purely to see if sending would work.

Is my method of storing an serialising an int into a char array (in CommandProcessor) not a good one? Cheers.

Comment: The overall problem is that you don't have a clear idea of how to do what you are trying to do in either C or C++ and as a result have this odd mix of mechanisms and mistakes.  That's going to be very hard to fix - you need a clarity of purpose and mechanism.  That it's network code then causes the issues and debugging challenges and potential variability of behavior to explode.  Are you aware of how `count` itself is stored in memory?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, is it possible that as most of the program was cut out, leaving only the relevant parts, that what remains seems confused? Just to briefly explain the "mechanism" I've gone through: 

All commands sent to the mbed are 16 bytes long. The first byte is the command, and the following 15 bytes are data (I thought a consistent message size would make life easier). In the main loop, receive up to 16 bytes (i.e. the entire message), and send to the CommandProcessor to de-serialise the data and execute the required action (In reality, this calls functions in other parts of the system

Comment: Is my approach wrong, or simply the way I've implemented it? Are the faults in the main file?

Comment: In the actual implementation, count is returned by another function. Either way, I would think that as it's being "copied" into message, it doesn't really matter?

Comment: No, it is not possible that this is a fragment of a "good" program written with sound understanding.  To really address all that is wrong in a more than piecemeal way would require that you find someone to offer pair-programming level advice on a re-write that starts by backing up to the design goals - which is of course far beyond the scope of a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thanks, I'll look into that. To point me in the right direction, given the method I've chosen (which I presume is acceptable?), which parts specifically do I need to look at, and can you point me to some resources which explain how to do what it is I'm trying to do on mbed? Also, is the idea of having a CommandProcessor class to de-serialise and process incoming "messages" a good one? As I see it, the issues are with how I've implemented networking, as opposed to how I process messages once they have been received and are in the system. Do you agree? Cheers

Comment: No, I don't agree.  The whole thing is mixed up from start to finish.  It can't meaningfully be fixed on a stack exchange site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Ok, I'll start from scratch. Where do you suggest I look to to get a better understanding of how this should be implemented? Code examples, etc. At this point I'm left feeling quite confused and not sure which direction to head in. Cheers